# Can I use a SSH key with git directly, without depending on ssh-agent?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, git, ssh-agent

I have a SSH key to allow me to push to a certain repository. No problem there with the key itself - however, I don't want to copy the key to a `.ssh` folder or leave the SSH key with ssh-agent (on other computers) and would rather have a portable script solution.

So I'm looking for the equivalent of how I can specify an identity with `-i` when connecting with `ssh`:

```
ssh -i /my/individual/path/id_rsa user@server
```

Also, with HTTPS on GitHub, for example, I can generate a token online and then do:

```
git remote add origin "https://TOKEN@github.com/USER/REPO.git"
```

Is there something similar for SSH keys, so I can use them with git directly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes... you can use ~/.ssh/config instead of ssh-agent
just add this in `~/.ssh/config` file

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile /my/individual/path/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHCOMMANDcode) environment variable can be used to change the SSH command that Git will use:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /path/to/your/id_rsa" git clone git@whatever
```

Alternatively, there is the [`core.sshCommand`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand) setting for `git config`:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i /path/to/your/id_rsa"
```

You can also use relative paths. So if you keep your `id_rsa` key in the parent folder of the repository root folder, the following config will make `git` commands use that key - no matter which repository folder is the current work directory:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ../id_rsa"
```

**Note:** You should also add `-F /dev/null` to those commands to prevent the local ssh configs `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config` from being read. For example, they might contain `AddKeysToAgent yes` which would automatically add the key to `ssh-agent`.